# DELPHI:  Put calculated value into a master detail where details are in a grid

Tags: delphi, master-detail, tclientdataset, tdbgrid

I have created a master-detail relation using ClientDataSets (Service & Addons).  The Services are displayed in a DBLookupComboBox (cboServices) and once a service is selected the Addons are displayed in DBGrid (grdMain).

The Addons has a checkbox to indicate the Addon is selected, a name field, a quantities field that the user can change, a unit price field and a total price field.

I have created a OnQuantityChange method to update the total price using the unit price and quantity but how do I get the actual data from the row to do the updating?  How do I reference  the various fields in order to do something like the following:

```
grdMain.GetActiveRow.Column['TotalPrice'] := 
   grdMain.GetActiveRow.Column['UnitPrice'] * grdMain.GetActiveRow.Column['Quantity'];
```

Comment: Isn't that a case for [Calculated Fields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields)?

Comment: If so how would I set that up?

Comment: Thanks, I did find info on how to do this using a calculated field.

Comment: I'm not sure if Uwe could provide comprehensive information about "how to set calculated fields" in a single answer.. In any case, you'd like to refer to the fields of the dataset themselves to have their value, not by the active row of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using calculated fields. I suggest you look at the following article for a detailed example with client dataset. Just search the article for calculated fields, you will find what you need.

[TClientDataset example](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29001)